# R 3.5 - csv file date conversion gets the year wrong

Tags: r, date, type-conversion

Code copied as is from R Studio console.

Here is the date field loaded from *csv* into data frame *data*:

```
 >data[1:10,'Date']
 [1] 7/1/2017 0:00 7/1/2017 0:00 7/1/2017 0:00 7/1/2017 0:00 7/1/2017 0:00 7/1/2017 0:00 7/1/2017 0:00 7/1/2017 0:00
 [9] 7/1/2017 0:00 7/1/2017 0:00
```

After converting it using `as.Date`, here is the result:

```
> as.Date (data[1:10,'Date'],"%m/%d/%y")
 [1] "2020-07-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-07-01"
[10] "2020-07-01"
```

The year 2017 becomes 2020 - the rest is correct - could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Forgot to mention in the *csv* file the dates are in the datetime format as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Csv File Date Field Format]

Comment: use a capital Y as in %Y

Comment: AArrggghh...! Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capital "Y" for a 4-digit year and small "y" for a 2-digit year